# jQuery Performance: Using a selector for each button or using one selector and checking the class?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery, which is better, performance-wise:

Adding an event handler for each button:

```
$(".toolbar .add").click() {
    // Add stuff here
}

$(".toolbar .remove").click() {
    // Remove stuff here
}

$(".toolbar .clear").click() {
    // Clear stuff here
}
```

Or adding one event handler and checking the class (or other relevant property) to see which action to take:

```
$(".toolbar .button").click() {
    if($(this).hasClass("add"))
        // Add stuff here
    } else if($(this).hasClass("remove")) {
        // Remove stuff here
    } else if($(this).hasClass("clear")) {
        // Clear stuff here
    }
}
```

Or perhaps there is a better way?

(If it makes any difference, I'm actually using `delegate`, not `bind` in my application)

Answer (score 2):

If you are really worried about performance, you might also do something like

```
var self = $(this);
if(self.hasClass("add"))
    // Add stuff here
} else if(self.hasClass("remove")) {
    // Remove stuff here
} else if(self.hasClass("clear")) {
    // Clear stuff here
}
```

Since calling `$(this)` executes code that wraps `this` into a jQuery object, and this way you won't be doing it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I would *guess* having it for each button would be better, since no client memory needed after click to distinguish between the button types (e.g. *if clause*), and your action is triggered directly. but maybe jquery is hiding more stuff. so let the experts help here :)

Answer (score 0):

`bind` is often better performance-wise than `delegate`. Delegate is designed to be used when the content of the root element can change.

---

EDIT : ** the code below is actually less optimized after tests (surprisingly). **

<strike>In order to optimize your example, you can do this :</strike>

```
var toolbar = $(".toolbar");
$(".add", toolbar).click() {
    // Add stuff here
}

$(".remove", toolbar).click() {
    // Remove stuff here
}

$(".clear", toolbar).click() {
    // Clear stuff here
}
```

This leads to the same result, but you look for $(".toolbar") only once!

However, jQuery has a system for caching some results. So I don't know if that really optimize.

---

EDIT2 : 
after testing that in Firebug :

```
console.time("first");
console.log($("div span"));
console.log($("div a"));
console.log($("div p"));
console.timeEnd("first");
```

and :

```
console.time("second");
var div = $("div");
console.log($("span", div));
console.log($("a", div));
console.log($("p", div));
console.timeEnd("second");
```

I get :

- first: 111ms
- second: 1323ms

So, it appears that what the alternative I gave may lead to counter-performance.

Comment: In my case I have to use `delegate` because the toolbar is loaded with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an overall performance difference (a real gap!) between Chrome (being extremely fast) and IE. This should be considered while testing.